# Given an arbitrary vector v, how will you resolve it in this non-orthonormal basis? Find a1, a2, a3?

Tags: vectors, change-of-basis

**V** = a1**f**1 + a2**f**2 +a3**f3**

Let us say you have three LI vectors f1,f2,f3, not necessarily
orthonormal – but since they are LI, they form a basis in E. Given an
arbitrary vector v, how will you resolve it in this non-orthonormal
basis? In other words, how will you find α1, α2, α3, s.t.
 **v** = α1 **f**1 + α2 **f**2 + α3 **f**3

Work directly with the given vectors and their dot-products – do not
resolve them in any orthonormal basis. Hint: αi =/ v·fi since the fi
are not orthonormal

Comment: Any conjectures? What do you know so that *we* can guide you in the right direction?

Comment: And what have you tried? Hint: Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: Here is a [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/144766) tutorial to make your question more readable.

Comment: I do not know how to start this, please help me :/